# Weather api returns nothing in SP hosted app

Tags: office-365, api

I am building a SP hosted app in Office 365. The app is to get current weather, I am using api but it returns nothing. I have tried with the same code in ASP.Net Web Application and it worked. Why is it not working in SP hosted app? As I said it return nothing.
Thx!

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Stockholm&APPID=23aabf5e2289b606d18f670397dcf3cb&units=imperial", function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#name").text(response.name);
                $("#temp").text(response.main.temp);
                $("#humidity").text(response.main.humidity);
            }); 
        });


<div id="name"></div>
        <br /> 
        <div id="temp"></div>
         <br /> 
        <div id="humidity"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is because you are making an http request on an https site, this is a security issue and browsers will block it. Check to see if they offer the api over https and use that instead.